# Probability and Straight line

Tags: probability

Two points are taken at random on the given straight line segment $AB$ of length $L$. Determine the probability that the length of none of the $3$ parts exceeds the given value $c$, where $L/3 \le c < L$.

I have tried dividing the line into segments for example, $AX = x$, the distance between $A$ and $X$.
and $XY = y$, the distance between the first and second arbitrary point and $YB = z$ the distance between $Y$ and the tip of the straight line.

Intuitively, I think the distance should be $1/3$ between them. But I don't know how to solve my problem.

Comment: Find $P(x > c)$. Then find $P(y>c|x)$. Then find $P(z>c|x,y).  Your intuition is good by the way, 1/3 is the average spacing.

Comment: Let $X$ be the first point, and let $Y$ be the second point, both uniformly distributed on $[0, L]$. WLOG, we can condition on $X < Y$, i.e. assume $X < Y$. Then the problem asks to find $P(X \leq c, Y - X \leq c, L - Y \leq c)$. You can draw this region on the plane and easily evaluate the probability geometrically as an area (assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent of course).

Comment: @Mason When calculating the probability for each of them, I use (1 / (b-a)) where b = X, and a = 0 ?

Answer (score 2):

let $L=1$

Let $x$ and $y$ be the locations of the 2 cuts
Let $S$ be the region defined by $0<y<x<1$

The three pieces will have lengths of $y, x-y$, and $1-x$

the condition that all three pieces have length less than $c$ is that the point $(x,y)$ is in the region $T$ of points satisfying$$(y<c) \cap(y>x-c)\cap ( x>1-c)$$
Then the probability that all three pieces have length less than $c$ is given by the ratio of the areas...
$$ P = \frac {A_{S\cap T}}{A_S}$$

When $\frac 13 < c < \frac 12$ a plot of the regions looks as in the image below where the region $T$ is shown in red...

[image]

$T$ is a single isosceles right triangle with two sides of length $3c-1$
so $$P=(3c-1)^2$$
When When $\frac 12 < c < 1$ a plot of the regions looks as in the image below ...

[image: regions]

The 3 blue isosceles right triangles each have two sides of length $1-c$, so the probability in this regime is $$P = 1 - 3(1-c)^2 $$

Putting it all together ...
$$ P(c) = \begin{cases}
(3c-1)^2  & \frac 13 \le c < \frac 12
\\ 1-3(1-c)^2  &  \frac 12 \le c \le 1 \end{cases}  $$

Comment: Good answer World War I

Comment: Thanks. I have a book of puzzles that asked for the probability that the three pieces could form a triangle ($c= \frac 12$) I found the answer some other way, but the solution in the back of the book was nothing but a diagram like the ones in my answer. I never understood that solution until tonight. Kudos to @Mason for pointing the way.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I have a question, because the interval of c is 1/3 to 1 at the end add up to the 2 odds you found, right?

Comment: I have adding a final statement which I think answers your question. Notice that the function is continuous at $c=\frac 12$ with $P(\frac 12)=\frac 14$